# Пройти итератором по всем таблицам базы в цикле FOR

Tags: sql, postgresql, миграция, stored-procedures

Необходимо написать хранимую процедуру для копирования данных из одной базы в другую.
Как можно пройтись по всем таблицам базы в цикле FOR?
Существует ли в SQL какой-то аналог итератора?

```
FOR table_iterator IN main_schema LOOP
   ...
END LOOP;
```

Спасибо

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Comment: PostgreSQL 11.8

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой запрос

```
SELECT
*
FROM
   pg_catalog.pg_tables
WHERE
   schemaname != 'pg_catalog'
   AND schemaname != 'information_schema';
```

Вы получите название таблиц. Далее динамический SQL вы получите данные по каждой таблице.